# Read a PNG image using Haxe

Tags: haxe

Using the Haxe programming language, is there any cross-platform way to read a PNG image, and get the pixel data from the image?

I have a file called stuff.png, and I want to obtain an array of RGB values from the image (as an integer array).

Comment: Does it have to be cross-platform? In flash it can be done with `BitmapData`.

Comment: @Banthar Yes, it has to be cross-platform.

Comment: [hxformat](http://code.google.com/p/hxformat/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fformat%2Fpng) can read PNG files but it's pretty low level.

Comment: @Banthar Is there any documentation available for the hxformat png library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example usage of the Haxe format library to read a PNG file. You need `-lib format` in your compiler args / build.hxml:

```
function readPixels(file:String):{data:Bytes, width:Int, height:Int} {
    var handle = sys.io.File.read(file, true);
    var d = new format.png.Reader(handle).read();
    var hdr = format.png.Tools.getHeader(d);
    var ret = {
        data:format.png.Tools.extract32(d),
        width:hdr.width,
        height:hdr.height
    };
    handle.close();
    return ret;
}
```

Here's an example of how to get ARGB pixel data from the above:

```
public static function main() {
  if (Sys.args().length == 0) {
    trace('usage: PNGReader <filename>');
    Sys.exit(1);
  }
  var filename = Sys.args()[0];
  var pixels = readPixels(filename);
  for (y in 0...pixels.height) {
    for (x in 0...pixels.width) {
      var p = pixels.data.getInt32(4*(x+y*pixels.width));
      // ARGB, each 0-255
      var a:Int = p>>>24;
      var r:Int = (p>>>16)&0xff;
      var g:Int = (p>>>8)&0xff;
      var b:Int = (p)&0xff;
      // Or, AARRGGBB in hex:
      var hex:String = StringTools.hex(p,8);
      trace('${ x },${ y }: ${ a },${ r },${ g },${ b } - ${ StringTools.hex(p,8) }');
    }
  }
```

Comment: Have you tested this code yet? I'm still setting up FlashDevelop for Haxe, so I haven't had a chance to test it yet.

Comment: This code doesn't seem to work in Haxe 3.2.1 (`format.png.Reader` and `format.png.Tools` don't exist).

Answer (score 0):

You can always access the pixel data with BitmapData.getPixels/BitmapData.setPixels.

If you are using haXe NME, you can use Assets.getBitmapData() to load an asset image file.

If you want to load images from network, then you can use Loader class, it can asynchronous loading remote images, but in flash please mind the cross-domain issue.

For more generic ByteArray -> BitmapData conversion, use following code:

```
var ldr = new Loader();
ldr.loadBytes(cast(byteArray)); // bytearray contains raw image data
var dp: DisplayObject = ldr.content; // actually ontent should be of Bitmap class
var bitmapData = new BitmapData(Std.int(dp.width), Std.int(dp.height), true, 0);
bitmapData.draw(dp);
```

Comment: There are a couple of issues here:
.loadBytes is asynchronous, so checking it immediately is not reliable.
Also, you don't need to blit the contents, they are already a bitmapdata. var bitmapData = cast(ldr.content, nme.display.BitmapData);

For an easier solution:
var bitmapData = nme.display.BitmapData.load("mypng.png");

Comment: Yes, you are right, the document says loadBytes is asynchronous, however this works all the time in practice, in both nme native & flash.

Comment: Hi, I applogise for the mistake in previous comments. As tested, Loader.loadBytes() works synchorously in an stand-alone flash player but asynchronously in browser plugin, so Matt are right, my code should be revised like this:
var ldr = new Loader();
ldr.loadBytes(cast(byteArray));
ldr.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, function(_) {
    data = cast(ldr.content, Bitmap).bitmapData;
} );

Comment: Is it necessary to load whole file in memory in Haxe, before one can access it's raw data? In Flash it is mandatory and... daunting.